# UITableViewRow Height 0 appear different on ios7 and ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I am working on xcode 5 and ios7, There is a table view with 7 sections, I have to show/hide three sections on conditions,for this I have done the height of that sections row to 0, it is working perfectly on ios7 but when I run on ios6 , the row with 0 height are also viewed. Please let me know  what should I do to prevent this in ios6.

IOS7 View 
[image: ios7 view]

In ios6 , the paypal row which is hidden in ios 7 is displayed. I do not have to show this when no is selected.

[image: ios6 view]

Code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section==3 && !isadvisor)
    { return 0;}
    if(indexPath.section==4 && !isadvisor)
    {return 0;}
    if(indexPath.section==5 && !isadvisor)
    { return 0;}
    if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0) {
        return 110;
    }
    if (indexPath.section==3 && indexPath.row==2) {
        return 125;
    }
    return 40;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{   return 7;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section==0)     return 8;
    else if(section==1) return [arr3 count]+1;
    else if(section==2) return 1;
    else if(section==3) return 5;
    else if(section==4) return [arr1 count]+1;
    else if(section==5) return [arr2 count]+1;
    else if(section==6) return 1;

    else return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help how should I fix this. 
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you put elements on a row with height 0 with a height other then based on the height of the cell? Perhaps the height of the cell is zero but not the elements on them.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Yes the elements height is not 0 but it is working correctly in io7 but no on ios6.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the rows in the hidden sections have a height of 0, I would change the number of sections so that those sections are just not in the tableview at all. This would improve the performance of the table view and eliminate any weirdness with cell sizes being 0.

So, in

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{   return 7;
}
```

Instead of just returning 7 all the time you would do:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{   return (isadvisor ? 7 : 4);
}
```

You would also need to accommodate the change in section in the number of rows for section and in the cells for indexPath methods.

A possibly cleaner way to do this would be to subclass your view controller so that if the user is an advisor a different view controller is instantiated that uses the 7 row logic, otherwise the base view controller uses the 4 row logic. That would reduce your number of 'isadvisor' tests down to just one.